# Law of Iterated Logarithm for autoregressive process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, limit-theorems

Suppose that $\{X_i\}$ is an $\mathrm{AR}(r)$, defined by:

$X_{i}= h(i) + \varepsilon_i $,

$h(i)=\alpha_1 X_{i-1} + \dots + \alpha_{r} X_{i-r}$

where $\{\varepsilon_i\}$ are i.i.d. ${\cal N}(0,1)$.

QUESTION:  Does $(X_{i}-h_i)X_{i-k}$, for $k=1..r$, satisfies the Law of Iterated Logarithm -- LIL?

In other words, is the equation (EQ1) below true?

$$
\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} 
\frac{
  \sum\limits_{i=1}^n  (X_{i}-h_i)X_{i-k}       
}{\sqrt{n \log\log n}} = c 
$$

for $c\in(0,\infty)$.

**More details**

Using Meyn & Tweedie, I could conclude that:

1. The AR process is a Linear State Space Model -- LSS (page 24)
2. LSS is a Markov Chain (page 9)
3. LSS with some conditions satisfies LIL (Theorem 17.0.1) for $V(x)=|x|^2 +1$ (page 456)

But, this $V(x)$, apparently, is not sufficient to provide "(EQ1)".

Basically, the Theorem 17.0.1 provides the LIL for $g^2 \leq V$.

In our case, $g((X_{i-r},\dots,X_i))=(X_{i}-h_i)X_{i-k} $

Thank you.

Paul

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a research problem, and you are trying to obtain LIL type results? I would suggest try to prove weak convergence and then use the result $h(x_n)\to h(x)$ weakly if $x_n \to x$ weakly for continuous functions $h$. (Most of ) Meyn Tweedie results on limit theorems for markov chains are essentially derived from Nummelin splitting and a combination of arguments for dealing with dependent sequences, and I don't think LIL type results are useful (if you have a lil result anyways events are w.p. $1$, if not then the limit itself is random).

Can you please detail me on the specific problem you are working on? I spent a year on LIL type results only to see that they are pretty much outdated. (I guess you are from engineering stream or most likely queuing theory because you are reading Meyn Tweedie).

Comment: For LIL, we need strong convergence. The proposed approach should not satisfy.

A don't think that LIL is outdated. Together with CLT and SLLN we have a "complete" view about the asymptotic behavior of a sequence (Feller 1 is a good reference for that).

Comment: @user24367: can you elaborate why you think LIL is outdated?